# Default model binder and complex types that include a list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, binding

I'm using RC1 of ASP.NET MVC.

I'm trying to extend [Phil Haack's](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) model binding example. I'm trying to use the default model binder to bind the following object:

```
public class ListOfProducts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    List<Product> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the code from Phil's example with some alterations:

Controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestBinding.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        //Action method on HomeController
        public ActionResult UpdateProducts(ListOfProducts productlist)
        {
            return View(productlist);
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListOfProducts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        List<Product> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

    <asp:Content ID="indexHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <form method="post" action="/Home/UpdateProducts">
            <input type="text" name="productlist.id" value="99" />
            <input type="text" name="productlist.Title" value="SomeTitle" />

            <input type="hidden" name="productlist.Index" value="0" />
            <input type="text" name="productlist.items[0].Name" value="Beer" />
            <input type="text" name="productlist.items[0].Price" value="7.32" />

            <input type="hidden" name="productlist.Index" value="1" />
            <input type="text" name="productlist.Items[1].Name" value="Chips" />
            <input type="text" name="productlist.Items[1].Price" value="2.23" />

            <input type="hidden" name="productlist.Index" value="2" />
            <input type="text" name="productlist.Items[2].Name" value="Salsa" />
            <input type="text" name="productlist.Items[2].Price" value="1.23" />

            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </asp:Content>
```

My problem is that the simple types (Id and Title) appears in the productlist object, but not the List. So:

- Is my code bad (wouldn't be surprised)?
- Can the default model binder handle the ListOfProducts objects?
- If the default model binder won't handle this type of object what do I need to do (examples if possible)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I'm a dummy!

My example doesn't work because the Items property of the ListOfProducts class is not public:

```
public class ListOfProducts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    List<Product> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I changed:

```
List<Product> Items { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public List<Product> Items { get; set; }
```

and my code then worked.

To conclude the default model binder does work with types that contain properties of type List.

Comment: You're not a dummy.  I was having the same problem, but it was because my list was not a property.  I had something analogous to:  public List<Product> Items, instead of public List<Product> Items { get; set; }

Answer (score 4):

Starting with RC 1:

- Hidden Index is no longer required
- The number in [] **must** start with 0 and **must** ascend.

Your numbering looks OK.

Also, I noticed that you used different casing on your items property name. That should not make a difference, but it's worth checking.