# Add dynamic form content in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic-content

I'm trying to add dynamic content to my mvc application.

I'm using Steven Sanderson post [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/), and thanks to it, I had some dynamic content into it.
Due some constraints of my application, I had to make a change into base Gift class.

The problem is that now the application doens't work.

**In my Model I have:**

```
public class Gift
{
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    //public double Price { get; set; }

    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

And now, I'm getting null values in gifts parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Gift> gifts)
{
    return View("Completed", gifts);
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

**EDIT:**
Here is my View code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Enviro2011.Models.Gift>>" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#addItem").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });

            $("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
                $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Gift List</h2>
    What do you want for your birthday?
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
    <div id="editorRows">
        <% foreach (var item in Model)
               Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item);
        %>
    </div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "Add", null, new { id = "addItem" }) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Finished" />
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

**Edit2**
I also have found out the post [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) from Phil Haack, and works just fine, but I can't implement the feature 'Add Book' !!!

Comment: The way in Sanderson's blog won't work directly since mvc can't directly bind the list type object. Can you also show your view codes here?

Comment: @xandy: are you sure when you say that MVC can't directly [bind the List type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616559/default-model-binder-and-complex-types-that-include-a-list) object???

Comment: What I mean is, you can't simply consider that as a variable and have MVC magically bind. Giving an index is the solution, but if it comes to list under another object, an simple index is not enough, customizing the bind behavior (in controller) or give a named index, like myList[0] is necessary.

Comment: @xandy: No problem. I just wanted to note that your first comment could lead to misunderstanding. @muek: as xandy already wrote you should add some of your view code to get more help...

Comment: @xandy I added the my view code

Comment: @muek You should checkout Knockout.JS. Steve Sanderson has another post about how to edit a list using Knockout + MVC and it's way simpler than the post you're looking at. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're looping through the model and not the items *in* the model.

Here's what you can do:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.MyList)  // <-- Add the ".MyList"
       Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item);
%>
```

We'll assume that your partial view receives only a string.

As far as your Ajax call not working, the problem there is that you're trying to submit twice, once using the actionLink and the other using Ajax.  Change the ActionLink to an explicit link with no action behind it:

```
<a id="addItem">Add another ...</a>
```

Then your jQuery Ajax call will fire.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have below action into your controllor

public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View("GiftEditorRow", new MyList());
}