# MVC 5 and List of Complex type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, model-binding

I've checked [MVC post a list of complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155607/mvc-post-a-list-of-complex-objects) as well as https://mhwelander.net/2014/03/26/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-not-occurring-when-posting-list-of-complex-types/ and a few other posts on the subject.

I would still rather ask the question, in order to understand and not simply copy paste an answer.

I have a complex type as below :

```
public interface ICaracteristic
{
    int value { get; set; }
    int max { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}

 public class BaseAttributes : ICaracteristic
{
    public int max { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    Random r = new Random();
}
```

And an object using multiples list of those types :

```
public class Character
{
    // Infos
    public string characterName { get; set; }
    public string playerName { get; set; }
    public IGame game { get; set; }
    // Caracteristics
    public List<ICaracteristic> baseAttr { get; set; }
    public List<ICaracteristic> skills { get; set; }
    public List<ICaracteristic> stats { get; set; }
    public List<ICaracteristic> spendPoints { get; set; }
}
```

I spare you the constructors and a few other methods.

Now, for the creation, I simply ask my user to enter the names of character and player, no problem, it works wonderfully as these are simple strings.

For the edit, I get the character in "my db" (based on xml sheets but that doesn't matter here), and display it this way :

```
   @model RPGmvc.Models.Character
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Character @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.characterName)</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="row">
    <!--SECTION BASE ATTRIBUTES-->
    <div class="col-md-3">


        <!-- @foreach (var item in Model.baseAttr)
        {
            <div>
                <label>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.name)</label>
                <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => item.value, new { @class = "form-control" })</p>
            </div>
        }
```

For the display, this works perfectly fine : it shows the correct names and values of each base attribute of my character (as well as the values of the other lists).

However when I click the "save" button below the form, the model that is posted reset the values of that list... but not the characterName.

What is weird is that it seems to mix that model's different constructors : the playerName, which I don't use in my edit template, is set to "toby determined" (as in my empty basic constructor),  but the characterName is the one of the current character being edited, instead of "new character" (as in said constructor)

I've tried to use a for instead of a foreach, thinking that maybe the index in the list would help to pass the correct values; but as I use an Interface that gave an error "Could not create an instance of interface".

I've tried with a custom editor, but it created the same problem as the "foreach".

(Here's the custom editor, just in case :

```
@model RPGmvc.Models.Caracteristic.ICaracteristic

<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.name)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.value)
</p>
```

Note that using an interface as model didn't cause any problem. )

I understand that I could apparently add an awful lot of annotations through my page to sort this, but since the custom editor didn't work and neither did the for with index, I first would like an explanation of what is happening :

What happens with the model binder here?
Could I "force" him to create an instance of an implementation of my interface, instead of the interface itself?
How come the HttpPost creates a custom object mixing my constructors ?

Thanks for your help.

---

Edit : Stephen Muelcke helped me by advising to remove the Interfaces from my model and using the real implementations. That almost worked :

Now my Post takes the correct values of the BaseAttributes, but the names of those are "null".
This is problematic since my datas comes from XML sheets, in which I search this way :

```
foreach (ICaracteristic battr in myCharac.baseAttr)
        {
            var currentNode = myDoc.SelectSingleNode("/character_sheet/base_attributes/" + battr.name.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower());
            currentNode.InnerText = battr.value.ToString();
        }
```

Which obviously fails, as name is "null".

I only did the change from "foreach" to "for" in the "Base Attributes" section. In that section, all names are set to null. In the other sections, no values are taken.

Any idea?

Comment: You cannot bind to intefaces (the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize an instance of an interface). And you need a `for` loop (or custom `EditorTemplate`) - a `foreach` loop will not work - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). You could create a custom `ModelBinder` to work with interfaces, but you would also need to post values indicating what concrete implementation to initialize

Comment: @StephenMuecke So, if I replace the "List<ICaracteristic> baseAttr" in my character model by a "List<BaseAttributes> baseAttr" , it should work?

Comment: Yes, so long as you use a `for` loop (or a custom `EditorTempate` for type of `BaseAttributes` and in the main view use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.baseAttr)`

Comment: So I have to strongly type every place i used an interface, and change the foreach in a for loop. Well, that kinda sucks for Interfaces :-/ I'll try this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke well, I've tried by replacing every occurence of the interface by its implementation : indeed, the form takes the value of the ICaracteristic, but it doesn't take its name any longer (-.-'). Any idea on what could cause that?

Comment: What do you mean by _but it doesn't take its name any longer_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'll edit original post to avoid too long discussion in comments with the explanations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132903/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-doctorprisme).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't , work policy blocks the page :(

Comment: Are you generating a form control for property `name`? (your question shows an `EditorTemplate` which does not have any form controls - just `DisplayFor()` and the code in the original `foreach` does not have a form control for `name` either)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've tried adding "new {@class="control-label" }" to the label generation, but it doesn't work any better. What kind of control should I generate?

Comment: You need `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.baseAttr[i].Name)` if in a `for` loop (or if you do not want to edit the value, you can use add `new { readonly = "readonly" }` or use `@Html.HiddenFor()` instead)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You rock man. Thanks a lot. Now I'll try to understand a bit but it works. If you provide an answer, I'll accept it. 

Last sub-question : is there another control I could use than text box? That is really ugly, even with the readonly ^-^

(Or maybe I could use Bind() attribute in the controller? User shouldn't be allowed to edit anything else than the Skills list theoretically)

Comment: Then I assume you don't want to edit it, so use `@DisplayFor()` and `@Html.HiddenFor()`, or add a class name to the readonly textbox and style it to look like you want.

Comment: @StephenMuecke indeed I don't want to edit it :) But `@Html.HiddenFor` will hide the value, won't it ? I'll go with the class I guess. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, the form control will be hidden, but include `DisplayFor()` as well (for the same property) to display its value in the view.

Comment: I'm about some time off, so feel free to add your own answer (but if you want an explanation of why interfaces wont work with the `DefaultModelBinder`, you will need to wait a week unless someone else adds an answer)

Answer (score 0):

So, since Stephen Muecke doesn't care for the reputation :

--You can't model bind to an interface.

--You can't do a foreach on a list because modelbinder needs the index.

--You need a "control" sort on every value you want to use, so for complex types you need one even on the display name.

A good solution is to do a for loop, in which you include an @Html.Hiddenfor in addition to a @Html.DisplayFor, so that the display name is not editable but still has a control.
For the Interface and modelbinder lack of interaction, the only solution is to use the implementation of the interface. Sadly.